# Wrong with Test and valid generators

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I've been working in my model, I came to generators part.

when I use to read test.csv file like this:

test_df = pd.read_csv("Test.csv")

Its going well!

and when I came to generator part:

```
def get_test_generator(test_df,  train_df, image_dir, x_col, y_cols, sample_size=100, batch_size=8, seed=1, target_w = 320, target_h = 320):
    """
    Return generator for test set using 
    normalization statistics from training set.

    Args:
      test_df (dataframe): dataframe specifying test data.
      image_dir (str): directory where image files are held.
      x_col (str): name of column in df that holds filenames.
      y_cols (list): list of strings that hold y labels for images.
      sample_size (int): size of sample to use for normalization statistics.
      batch_size (int): images per batch to be fed into model during training.
      seed (int): random seed.
      target_w (int): final width of input images.
      target_h (int): final height of input images.
    
    Returns:
        test_generator (DataFrameIterator): iterators over test set
    """
    print("getting train generators...")
    # get generator to sample dataset
    raw_train_generator = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_df, 
        directory=IMAGE_DIR, 
        x_col="Image", 
        y_col=labels, 
        class_mode="raw", 
        batch_size=sample_size, 
        shuffle=True, 
        target_size=(target_w, target_h))
    
    # get data sample
    batch = raw_train_generator.next()
    data_sample = batch[0]

    # use sample to fit mean and std for test set generator
    image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=True,
        featurewise_std_normalization= True)
    
    # fit generator to sample from training data
    image_generator.fit(data_sample)

    # get test generator
 

    test_generator = image_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=test_df,
            directory=image_dir,
            x_col=x_col,
            y_col=y_cols,
            class_mode="raw",
            batch_size=batch_size,
            shuffle=False,
            seed=seed,
            target_size=(target_w,target_h))
    return test_generator
```

when I run this cell in Jupyter :

```
IMAGE_DIR = '/Users/awabe/Desktop/Project/PapilaDB/FundusImages test'

test_generator= get_test_generator(test_df, train_df, IMAGE_DIR, "Image", labels)
```

to read the images

it give me the error:

```
getting train generators...
Found 0 validated image filenames.
Found 488 validated image filenames.
/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py:1139: UserWarning: Found 488 invalid image filename(s) in x_col="Image". These filename(s) will be ignored.
  warnings.warn(
/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3432: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:182: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  ret = um.true_divide(
/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:265: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  ret = _var(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof,
/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:223: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  arrmean = um.true_divide(arrmean, div, out=arrmean, casting='unsafe',
/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:254: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  ret = um.true_divide(
```

(the 488 images in the second line belongs to the train generator which works fine)

where is the wrong here?

Comment: Please share the entire traceback error code. By seeing mentioned error code, It seems these are only warnings which you can suppress using - 
`import logging, os`
`logging.disable(logging.WARNING)`
`os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"`. Please have a look at this similar [example](https://vijayabhaskar96.medium.com/tutorial-on-keras-imagedatagenerator-with-flow-from-dataframe-8bd5776e45c1) for your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the images name in the column Image should contain the image name + the extension. for example:

assume the name in the directory file is: image1.jpg

so the name in the csv should be: image1.jpg

if you write it as: image1

you will get an error back.

so simple .

thanks to the upper guy TFer2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).